# Misconception with the use of Green's functions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, greens-functions

Problem: Consider a spherical shell of radius R centered on the origin. The top-right quadrant ($0<θ<90$
degrees, $0<φ<90$ degrees) is at a voltage V. The rest of the sphere is grounded. Determine the potential at the origin.

I am trying to solve this problem using Green's Functions.

For a sphere, $$\phi = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_o}\int\rho G_D d\tau'+\frac{-1}{4\pi}\int\phi(r')\frac{\partial{G_D}}{\partial n'}da'$$

Since charge density is zero everywhere, I know the first term goes to zero. When I find the derivative of $G_d$ wrt $n' = r'$ (because $r'$ points outside the spherical volume) at $r' = R$, I get $$\frac{\partial{G_D}}{\partial n'} = \frac{\frac{r^2}{R}-R}{[r^2-2rR\cos(\gamma)+R^2]^\frac{3}{2}}$$

where $\gamma$ is the angle between the r and r' vectors. Now I have to take the integral of this on the surface area of the sphere where V is defined as the potential.

However, since I am looking for the potential at the origin, r has to go to zero. This means there is **no** angle $\gamma$ between r and r', so what do I integrate over?

When I plug in $r = 0$ into the integral, the potential becomes $0$ at the origin. When I assume there is **no** angle $\gamma$ between $r$ and $r'$ such that $\gamma = 0$, then the $\sin(\gamma)$ term in $da' = r^2\sin(\gamma)d\gamma' d\phi'$ yields zero and just like before the whole thing goes to zero. I do not think this is correct. What am I doing wrong? I must have some misconceptions about the process, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I've been thinking about this for a while.

For other students:

sin$(\gamma)$ here should be sin$(\gamma')$, where $\gamma'$  is **DIFFERENT** (obviously!; I don't know how or why I missed this from the beginning) from the angle in cos$(\gamma)$. Also, r in $da'$ term be r' = R.

From there it is just basic integration.